# Does grails inherit hasMany relationships?

Tags: grails, inheritance

Can someone tell me what will happen in the following scenario?  Will one hasMany overwrite the other or will they both be respected?

```
class Parent {
    static hasMany = [attributes: Attribute]
}

class Child extends Parent {
    static hasMany = [games: Game]
}
```

When I attempt to run my app with code similar to above, it fails with a message of "null" which is quite helpful.  :)

Comment: Try run-app --verbose --stacktrace, maybe this generates more output.

Comment: The envers plugin was causing the exception.  As soon as I added the @Audited decoration to one of my domain classes, everything saved as it should.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something else was causing the problem and not the actual code itself.  So to provide an answer to my question, both hasMany relationships are supported in the Child.